# Bind domain to October CMS theme folder

Tags: url, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I am using October CMS and would like to bind a theme folder to a separate domain.

Will this affect the domain that October CMS is currently on?

Thank you.

Comment: `bind a theme folder to a separate domain` by that means you need separate related theme for each domains correct ?

Comment: Basically the main website is on its own domain, and only the themes folder is associated to another domain.
What will the effect of this have on the October CMS website?

Comment: ok domain is different but hosting files / [October Cms Files - Theme Folder ]  are on same place on same hosting correct ?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Just wondering if it it can be done. The idea is to associate the other domain to just the themes folder and not to a separate server.